# Resolving from ServiceStack's IoC container which depends on another registered element

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack, inversion-of-control, ioc-container

I have a class which should have an instance of a `Service` (to access the database and other services):

```
public class MyFoo : IFoo
{
    public Service Service { get; set; }

    public MyFoo (Service service)
    {
        Service = service;
    }
}
```

I want to register this class with ServiceStack's IoC container. Currently, I am doing it like this

```
container.Register<IFoo> (c => new MyFoo (c.TryResolve<MyService> ()));
```

This does work fine, but it strikes me as pretty ugly to resolve an element in a container while registering another one. Is there a more elegant way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also Register the dependency [using one of the AutoWired APIs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/The-IoC-container#autowire-registration), e.g:

```
container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<MyFoo,IFoo>()
```

Also ServiceStack will inject each public property with any registered dependencies so you don't need your constructor, e.g:

```
public class MyFoo : IFoo
{
    public Service Service { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I have to manually register a Service in the AppHost like `container.RegisterAutoWiredAs<MyService,Service> ();`
Is there a way around this?

Comment: @mat Wait are you talking about ServiceStack Services as a dependency? You should never register ServiceStack Services, they're automatically registered by ServiceStack. See the [Service Gateway](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Service-Gateway) for examples of calling Services within another Service.

Comment: I do mean a ServiceStack Service, yes. I currently use the `ResolveService` method, thanks for the tip about the Gateway.
But my problem remains, that I somehow need to be able to resolve my services (or access a Gateway) within my interface.

Comment: @mat You should pass in `base.Gateway` from your original Service as a param into your dependency API, it can't be injected because it needs access to the incoming `IRequest` which isn't available from the IOC. You can also use the `HostContext.AppHost.GetServiceGateway(IRequest)` or `HostContext.ResolveService<T>(IRequest)` singletons but they still need the `IRequest` for the current request which you can get from `base.Request` from your original Service or in ASP.NET Hosts you can get an `IRequest` with `HostContext.TryGetCurrentRequest()` but that only works in ASP.NET, so not recommended

Comment: Would you consider it bad practice, if I pass the Service instead of the Gateway to my interface? I'd prefer that, because I'd have access to the database, too, in that case.

Comment: @mat it's fine either way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @mythz